# Creating Job from REST API returns a request property name error

Tags: rest, azure, azure-media-services

I have my Asset and MediaProcessor ready. Now I am trying to encode my asset. When I send the request specified in the tutorial (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj129574.aspx):

```
{
   "Name":"CurlTestJob",
   "InputMediaAssets":[
      {
         "__metadata":{
            "uri":"https://wamsbluclus001rest-hs.cloudapp.net/api/Assets('nb%3Acid%3AUUID%3A429967f5-4709-4377-bab2-4680ae2a0dd87')"
         }
      }
   ],
   "Tasks":[
      {
         "Configuration":"H.264 HD 720p VBR",
         "MediaProcessorId":"nb%3Ampid%3AUUID%3A2e7aa8f3-4961-4e0c-b4db-0e0439e524f5",
         "TaskBody":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><taskBody><inputAsset>JobInputAsset(0)</inputAsset><outputAsset>JobOutputAsset(0)</outputAsset></taskBody>"
}
]
}
```

I get the following response

```
{
    "odata.error":
    {
        code: "";
        message:
        {
            lang: "en-US";
            value: "Parsing request content failed due to: Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type";
        };
    };
}
```

I am using api-version 2.2

Can someone explain to me where am I wrong?

Comment: Did you figure out what was wrong

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the Header "DataServiceVersion: 2.0"

I ran into the same issue when using "DataServiceVersion: 3.0"

Answer (score 1):

The error says that properties in json file does not match the properties in the deserialized type. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.mediaservices.client.iasset.aspx shows that IAsset has property Uri, but say nothing about __metadata. You could try to change your json to

```
 "InputMediaAssets":[{
        "Uri":"https://wamsbluclus001rest-hs.cloudapp.net/api/Assets('nb%3Acid%3AUUID%3A429967f5-4709-4377-bab2-4680ae2a0dd87')"
  }],
```

Comment: You provided reference to .NET SDK, but we are using RESTFULL API. __metadata is defined in RESTFULL sample http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj129574.aspx

Comment: I saw that sample. SDK classes and REST API should be synchronized in terms of public properties, that's why I pointed to the difference between classes and sample in MSDN.